# Error CS1001: Identifier expected. I need some assistance

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im making a code for fade in, fade out scene transitions and there seems to be a problem. It says "CS1001: Identifier expected" On unity console panel.

I have tried

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Enter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string sceneName;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D, other)
     {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
        }
     }
}
```

But still, atleast 4, FOUR errors saying "CS1001: Identifier expected". I am a beginner coder and this is bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

In `private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D, other)`, you don't want the `,`.

Iit should be `Collider2D other`:

- a parameter named `other`
- of type `Collider2D`

You should use a comma to separate multiple parameters, like `FindPerson(String firstName, String lastName)`

Comment: That helped, but now theres still 4 "Identifier Expected"

Comment: Apparently (I cannot see without code) you have there also situations where the compiler expects an identifier (named variable) to follow a type (class name), but either you forgot the identifier, or you used (for instance) a `,` or `;` in an wrong position

Comment: `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Enter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string sceneName;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneName");
        }
     }
}` This was the code. Currently there is only 2 identifier expected and im tryng real hard.

Comment: That posted code *looks* fine. Are you sure those errors are in this code? On what line(s) are those errors reported? I would expect that your editor marks the error locations